# Find the general solution of the following first order differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8x^3+3x^4}{y^4}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have multiplied both sides by $y^4$

which gives me $\frac{dy}{dx}y^4=x^3(3x+8)$

Then do I integrate both sides with respect to x?

$\int\frac{dy}{dx}yx^4dx=\int{x^3(3x+8)dx}$

Am I still on the right track?

So I get $\frac{yx^5}{5}=\frac{3x^5}{5}+2x^4+c$

Do I just solve for y after this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By separation of variables, you get $$y^4 \,dy = (3x^4 + 8x^3)\,dx$$

Now, integrate each side of the equation:

$$\int y^4 \,dy = \int (3x^4 + 8x^3)\,dx$$

$$\iff \frac 15 y^5 = \frac 35x^5 + 2x^4 + c$$

Comment: And yes, you may solve now for $y$, by multiplying through by 5, then taking the fifth root of each side.

Comment: awesome thank you! i thought I might be right, but I wasnt sure whether I just went off on a tangent